# How to enforce my geo location is real GPS, not just my network endpoint's passive location?

Tags: android, android-gps

We have in-house tablets, that we control, and we have the requirement that their recorded location be as accurate as possible. I do everything I should to turn on real GNSS GPS, but `getLastKnownLocation("gps")` always returns `null`.

We use a Samsung Galaxy Tab A7, SM-T500, whose specifications swear it has a real GPS GNSS radio receiver. Google Maps identifies my secret lair correctly.

Our `AndroidManifest.xml` requests GPS permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:foregroundServiceType="location"
        ...
        >
```

In the tablet's Settings, our app has Location permission "Only while app is in use," which is fine because our app dominates our tablet and is interactive. Our tablet is not used in a vehicle, so the location only needs to be accurate within the last 10 minutes or so.

`locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` returns `true`, as does that call with `PASSIVE_PROVIDER` and `NETWORK_PROVIDER`. The "fused" provider is not available.

Then we call this, to pull every kind of location and return the most accurate one:

```
private static Location getLastKnownLocation(@NonNull LocationManager locationManager) {
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
    Location bestLocation = null;

    for (String provider : providers) {
        Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (l == null)
            continue;

        if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy())
            bestLocation = l;  //  Found best last known location: %s", l);
    }

    return bestLocation;
}
```

All we get is "passive." Do GPS locations specifically require a round-trip thru `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`, or is `getLastKnownLocation()` good enough?

Comment: requestLocationUpdates is the answer

Comment: yeah I figured. my onCreate() is obese as it is...

Answer (score 0):

Similar answers are elsewhere but this thread deserves closure. It seems `getLastKnownLocation()` does not work with GPS and GNSS satellites, so as Phantom Lord prompted the correct fix is to enable my main activity for GPS:

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {`

Then in `onCreate()` turn on a listener:

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (locationManager != null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;  // TODO  spank user
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 10, this);
    }
```

Then catch the updates:

```
private Location gpsLocation = null;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    gpsLocation = location;
}
```

Now a new question: Why is the passive location accuracy ~5 meters while the GPS location accuracy is ~14 meters? This is a naive tablet, so it certainly doesn't know my home address and such. According to my internet spam, my IP address is in a nearby city...

Comment: Maybe it triangulates with antennas and wifi. However gps is the best choice for it is more affordable.